# Which is LESS executable file?

Tags: npm

Under 'npm' folder, I have lessc and lessc.cmd file. However, there is a node_modules folder which contains a lessc file as well. 
I am trying to set up a executable file in Koala precompiler, which file I should reference to ?

```
AppData\Roaming\npm > lessc & lessc.cmd
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin > lessc
```

Also, when I type npm less -v, it only shows 2.11.3, however, I am pretty sure I installed v2.5. How do I know which above files are 2.11 or 2.5?

Comment: depends on your OS (assuming it's Windows - use `lessc.cmd`, it's a wrapper that invokes the `bin/lessc` node script within `node` executable).

Comment: `npm *** -v` - actually prints `npm` version (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version). To find installed `less` version use `lessc -v`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, thank you so much for your help. :) So what exactly is the lessc file that is in the same folder(npm) as lessc.cmd? Is it 'local' lessc bin file? Btw, if you make first two answers as the 'answer', I will vote it.